# Unity 2D-3D, проблема с постановкой кода к объекту

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Здраствуйте, снова вас беспокоит начинающий программист на Unity. Спасибо всем кто мне помог мне в прошлые разы, я очень вам благодарен!
Я с новой проблемой
Хочу написать код для случайной генерации объектов на определенной территории другого объекта, пишет ошибку, абсолютно не понимаю как исправить ошибку.
Помогите пожалуйста!
Также на втором слайде показано что я хочу перенести код на объект (Прямоугольник) 3D.
Жду ответа!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform spawnPos;
[SerializeField] Vector2 range;
[SerializeField] GameObject enemy;

void Start() 
{
    StartCoroutine(Spawn());
}


IEnumerator Spawn() (ошибка с словом Start)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Vector2 pos = spawnPos.position + new Vector3(0, Random.Range(-range.y, range.y));
    Instantiate(enemy, pos, Quaternion.identity);
    Repeat();
}

void Repeat() 
{
    StartCoroutine(Spawn());
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: //вот так можно оставлять комментарии в коде

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка покажется тебе простой как только ты поймешь что имя твоего метода использует уже существующее название, в данном случае твой класс имеет такое же название, поэтому выходит конфликт, невозможно определить к какому обьекту ты ссылаешься

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!